# how to use pass paramters to controller every time an item is selected in select tag in rails 3?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

this my select statement, I guess I cannot figure out how to make it work:

```
<%= select("post", {project_id: @project, word_id: @word_id}, 
              @words[count].synonyms.all.collect {|syn| [ syn.name ] ,
              {:id=>"Menu1_Id", :class => "Menu1_Class", :onchange => "alert('hey')"}) %>
```

@project and @word_id are the parameters I want to make it pass to the controller,
where to add my url path ?

Comment: could you post the html produced by this

Comment: <select id="post_{:project_id=&gt;25, :synonym_id=&gt;24, :word_id=&gt;nil}" name="post[{:project_id=&gt;25, :synonym_id=&gt;24, :word_id=&gt;nil}]"><option value="دوس">دوس</option>
<option value="إضغط">إضغط</option>
<option value="انقر">انقر</option></select>

Comment: if you want to send project_id and word id with request you can put them as hidden fields
**or** if both are changing with each option you can merge them in one string in the value of each option tag and parse this string in the server side